# Concavity in discrete domain

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, convex-analysis

I have question with respect to concave functions. This came up in my research.

Suppose we have a real valued function $f(x)$ which is concave in $x\in \mathbb{R}$ Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of natural numbers.

Can we say that $f(x)$ is concave in $x\in \mathbb{N}$? If so how is concavity defined with respect to the discrete domain.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a function $f:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb R$, it would be natural to extend it preserving continutity to $\bar f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ by making it affine on each segment $[n,n+1]$. Then you are able to check if its convex or not. Another way to define a concave function, I think, is to check if $g:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb R$, $g(n) = f(n+1)-f(n)$ is an increasing function.

Comment: Thank you. I need a little more explanation of the second part of your answer please. If we find out that $g(n)=f(n+1)-f(n)$ is increasing then does the theorems defined for convex continuous functions apply to the discrete function $g(n)$?

Comment: @MLT In fact, my two definitions of discrete convexity are equivalent, it's sufficient to draw a picture and notice that $g(n)$ is the right-side derivative of $\bar f$ in the point $n$ and $g(n-1)$ is a left-side derivative of $\bar f $ in the point $n$. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties) you can see where my idea for $g$ comes from.

Comment: Think it should be that $g(n)$ is a _decreasing_ function